# Formula for 95% confidence interval for $R^2$

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, inference, r-squared

I googled and searched on stats.stackexchange but I cannot find the formula to calculate a 95% confidence interval for an $R^2$ value for a linear regression. Can anyone provide it?

Even better, let's say I had ran the linear regression below in R. How would I calculate a 95% confidence interval for the $R^2$ value using R code.

```
lm_mtcars <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)
```

Comment: Well you know the relationship between the correlation $r$ and $R^2$ is that you are squaring the correlation coefficient to get $R^2$ so why not calculate the confidence interval for $r$ and then square the lower and upper limits of the interval?

Comment: @ZERO: that will work in a simple linear regression, that is, with a single predictor and an intercept. It won't work for multiple linear regression with more than one predictor.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, very true! I guess I was basing it off of his `R` code where there is only one regressor but that is a very good point to clarify.

Comment: http://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc/formulas.aspx?id=28

Comment: You can e.g. use a very small R function https://github.com/mayer79/R-confidence-intervals-R-squared based on properties of the non-central F-distribution.

Comment: $R^2$ is not a population parameter so is not clear what would be the meaning of the confidence interval ... (exception if you have sampled from a multinormal population)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: The OP should write "for the *true* $R^2$", which is well defined.

Answer (score 18):

You can always bootstrap it:

```
> library(boot)
> foo <- boot(mtcars,function(data,indices)
        summary(lm(mpg~wt,data[indices,]))$r.squared,R=10000)

> foo$t0
[1] 0.7528328

> quantile(foo$t,c(0.025,0.975))
     2.5%     97.5% 
0.6303133 0.8584067
```

[Carpenter & Bithell (2000, Statistics in Medicine)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/%28SICI%291097-0258%2820000515%2919:9%3C1141::AID-SIM479%3E3.0.CO;2-F/abstract) provide a readable introduction to bootstrapping confidence intervals, though not specifically focused on $R^2$.

Comment: (+1) It might be of interest that the approximate formula quoted by @Durden, with $n=32$ and $k=1$ gives the interval $(0.546,0.960)$. It would be almost perfectly correct if we drop the factor of $2$ multiplying the SE in that formula!

Comment: May also be worth noting that you can get other types of confidence interval (e.g., BCa) from the bootstrap resampling distribution using `boot.ci()`.

Answer (score 11):

In R, you can make use of the `CI.Rsq()` function provided by the [psychometric](https://cran.r-project.org/package=psychometric) package. As for the formula it applies, see [Cohen et al. (2003)](https://books.google.com/books?id=gkalyqTMXNEC&pg=PA88), *Applied Multiple Regression/Correlation Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences*, p. 88:

$SE_{R^{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{4R^{2}(1-R^{2})^{2}(n-k-1)^{2}}{(n^2 - 1)(n+3)}}$

Then, the 95% CI is your $R^{2} \pm 2 \cdot SE_{R^{2}}$.

Comment: (1) $(1-R^2)$ is squared in your reference. (2) It is important to note that "$R^2$" is intended to be the sample value rather than the population value (which clearly is what "$R^2$" refers to in the question, whence the potential for confusion). (3) It is also important that this is only an asymptotic ("large-sample") result, giving "adequate approximations" for "$n-k-1 \gt 60$".  (I believe $k+1$ counts an intercept plus the number of independent variables.) It would be useful to see a worked example supported by simulation, because this interval looks too wide.

Comment: According to Wishart (1931) the formula is unsuitable for nonnormal distributions.

Comment: Is there an approximation available for non-normal distributions?