# When a regressor is almost statistically significant

Tags: regression

I would like to ask a question regarding a backwards stepwise elimination for MLR.
I recently saw a lecture on an online course at udemy.com and it demonstrated three steps to go from a four regressor model (first model) down to a one regressor model (fourth model). The third model had a regressor that was almost statistically significant at 0.06 and that is why the fourth model arose, the elimination of this variable.

However the third model did actually have a better adjusted r-squared value (0.9483) than the fourth model (0.9454). The guy who was teaching made the decision that the third model was more appropriate because of the combination of the variable being almost significant and the third model having a slightly higher adjusted r-squared.

I'm just interested in some opinions on this decision/scenario?
Please.

[image]

Ok, now I have added the results from the anova using the left-hand model. Clearly, Marketing.Spend is still not significant without type I error. So this gives more impetus not to include Marketing.Spend in the model.
See Below...

[image]

Comment: could you show your model's summary: 3rd and 4th cases?

Comment: Please check summaries @AlexeyBurnakov

Comment: thank you. I would say the model with additional regressor feels unnecessary or more overfitting-prone. I suggest that first thing you do in a small task like that is: run contrasts using stats::anova, sypplying the full model in there (left screen) in. Look again at the p-value associated with the Marketing.Spend term. Second, **because of the combination of the variable being almost significant and the third model having a slightly higher adjusted r-squared.** this is very weak. If you run a comparison of the 2 R_Squared values, you would not find significant difference.

Comment: besides, it is always better to choose a less complicated model that does not show **significant** performance drop, and obviously your model with just two coefficients is better as you do not gain anything significantly by adding one more (noisy) term.

Comment: Oh yeah, simpler model makes sense, well said @AlexeyBurnakov. I will investigate contrasts with stats::anova. Thanks for your opinion.

Comment: @ Bucephalus, one more thing, a killer one. Given that you look at 2-3 test statistics associated with your coefficients, you have to adjust your alpha level. I understood you were taught to use 0.05 as a threshold for the p-value. In your case this thresholds becomes 0.05 / 2 and 0.05 / 3 respectively for each model. Thus the third coefficient goes away smoothly. (Read about multiple comarison problem.)

Comment: Yes I was taught to use 0.05. I learned slr and mlr only this year at university. Thanks @AlexeyBurnakov, I will look up multiple comparison problem. I'm not sure what you mean by 2-3 test statistic and why you divide 0.05 by 2 and 3. I just looked up multiple comparison problem on wikipedia for this topic it mentions the Bonferroni Correction which looks like what you have done.

Comment: I mean if you look at 3 p-values in your summary, you cannot legally compare them to 0.05 (or whatever alpha you want to use). You get the Type 1 error rate as follows: 1 - (1 - 0.05) ^3 = 0.143. That means that using 0.05 you can select at least one insignificant coefficient from 3 with this probability.

Comment: OK, I see I have a lot to learn @AlexeyBurnakov. Thanks.

Comment: you're welcome. feel free to update your question with more results and ask for interpretation.

Comment: Alexey, can you please see my addition to the post to verify that I understood what you want me to do with stats::anova @AlexeyBurnakov

Comment: I guss we are in the same time zone )) I saw the addition. Well, it is almost exactly the same as the model, but it hapenns not always. Even if you feel "OK" with 0.06 as being almost significant (some researchers do, but it is sinful), you cannot say your R squared increased **significantly**. To prove that you can use tools, see here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175026/formula-for-95-confidence-interval-for-r2

Comment: I summarized all in one answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm just interested in some opinions on this decision/scenario?
>   Please.

Following the Occam's Razor principle, you should better avoid complicating a model with dimensions that are not significantly influencing the model's quality.

Besides, it is recommended to adjust p-value / alpha level in your study to the number of hypothesis checks that have to be made in order to derive an answer. You can refer to: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/p.adjust.html for p-value adjustment, or to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem for the way to adjust the alpha.

If contrasts have not provided you with significant p-values, there is no point whatsoever to over-complicate the model (which will probably turn more overfit).

One more reason is to consider comparison of the coefficient of determination, and if it has returned insignificant p-value (one tailed), you can rightfully decide to keep the simpler model.

Comment: When I did this unit at university we learned about "contrasts" such as orthogonal contrasts. I have a feeling you're not talking about these but you were intending for me to do what I did, just comparing the test statistics with ANOVA. Is that correct? @AlexeyBurnakov

Comment: No, we are definitely not in the same timezone. It's 21:40 here Sunday night. I'm on the east coast of Australia.

Comment: @Bucephalus, **, just comparing the test statistics with ANOVA. Is that correct?** These test statistics are F-tests which show if your models (or model coefficients) as a factor significantly influence the mean residual value.

Comment: @Nick Cox, sorry for my bad format and English as a I am trying to type fast.

Comment: Your English is immeasurably better than my Russian.