# Formula for confidence intervals for corelation of samples from non-normal distributions

Tags: regression, correlation, confidence-interval, r-squared, pearson-r

My question is similar to [Formula for 95% confidence interval for $R^2$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175026/formula-for-95-confidence-interval-for-r2) (I indeed want to corelate predicted with true values to obtain $R^2$).

The problem is their distribution is not normal. I wanted to use [Cohen et al. (2003)](https://books.google.com/books?id=gkalyqTMXNEC&pg=PA88) approach. However I dig through *Correlations redux* Olkin and Finn (1995) and *The mean and second moment coefficient, in samples from a normal population* Wishart (1931), from which the formula originates. Wishart states explicitely:

> [...] althought the utility of this quantity, for a distribution which is far from normal, is not so great as would at first sight appear.

Is there known a formula for such CI, or do I have to resort to bootstrap-like approach?

Comment: The formula, as you already note, would have to depend on the distribution: there is no universal formula, just as there isn't even a universal formula for the CI of a mean.  Would you like to provide some specific distributional assumptions?

Comment: Unfortunately the only thing I can assume is that number of samples is large (>> 100). In case of mean I think it may be enough due to the central limit theorem. But I have no idea how to use it in case of corelation.

Comment: @whuber I may also assume that both variance and mean of distributions are finite

Comment: That's not going to get you very far.  In fact, you already made that assumption by supposing $R^2$ exists.

Comment: @whuber then it seems bootstrap is the only option