# Can you calculate confidence interval on pseudo-$R^2$ in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, confidence-interval, r-squared, effect-size

Can you calculate confidence intervals for pseudo-$R^2$ in logistic regression that is reported in published literature? If so, how?

Comment: Related-but-not-a-duplicate: [Formula for 95% confidence interval for $R^2$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/175026/1352)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure how meaningful are pseudo-$R^2$ metrics, but one could bootstrap to get this. Here is some R code, using `pscl::pR2()` function to get a pseudo-$R^2$:

```
library(pscl)
# simulating data -------------------------------------------
set.seed(1839)
n <- 1500
x <- runif(n)
y <- cut(x + rnorm(n), 2, c("disagree", "agree"))

# fit model -------------------------------------------------
model <- glm(y ~ x, family = binomial("logit"))
pR2(model)[["McFadden"]]

# bootstrap -------------------------------------------------
number_of_resamples <- 5000
bootstrap_pr2 <- sapply(1:number_of_resamples, function(j) {
  bootstrap_cases <- sample(c(1:n), n, TRUE)
  pR2(glm(y[bootstrap_cases] ~ x[bootstrap_cases], 
          family = binomial("logit")))[["McFadden"]]
})

# report 95% CI ---------------------------------------------
mean(bootstrap_pr2) - 1.96 * sd(bootstrap_pr2)
mean(bootstrap_pr2) + 1.96 * sd(bootstrap_pr2)
```

---

Note that I am assuming the $R^2$ is normally distributed when I calculated the 95% CI. This is not true, since it is bounded at zero. So this is an imperfect—but acceptable—way of calculating a CI. In some circumstances, you might get a negative lower bound using this method; I would just report that as zero.

Comment: +1. [Carpenter & Bithell (2000, Statistics in Medicine)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/%28SICI%291097-0258%2820000515%2919:9%3C1141::AID-SIM479%3E3.0.CO;2-F/abstract) provide a readable introduction to bootstrapping confidence intervals, though not specifically focused on $R^2$.

Comment: But is this meaningful? $R^2$ is not a population parameter, since it depends also on the design ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen not sure if it is meaningful, but I’ll defer to OP on their specific use-case. Bootstrapping is a way to get at a CI, though.