# Calculating Significance

Tags: regression, statistical-significance

I have a model that I have fit to some data with an r^2 value of 0.83. But the fit is based on only 14 points of data which would be less significant than say 200.  What is the best way to show how having such a low number of data points leads to less significance in the results?

| actual | model |
| --- | --- |
| 7092.34 | 7327.17 |
| 7710.31 | 7859.76 |
| 8786.96 | 8485.04 |
| 8114.80 | 8560.08 |
| 13233.43 | 14921.28 |
| 14596.82 | 15890.70 |
| 14880.42 | 17162.47 |
| 17106.78 | 18605.62 |
| 17669.47 | 19862.65 |
| 18560.41 | 22032.17 |
| 19743.79 | 22595.54 |
| 19432.31 | 23302.04 |
| 20953.62 | 24952.85 |
| 68873.56 | 41010.74 |

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you mean by “significant”? That term has a technical meaning in statistics (related to a p-value) that is not the same as in colloquial English.

Comment: I guess you want to demonstrate that with a larger number of observations the probability of finding a statistically significant slope (say, or another model parameter) is larger? Well, that's not necessarily true. You have to *assume* that the alternative hypothesis is true to be able to show that (and how to do it depends on how exactly and what you're testing).

Comment: Hi Dave, Christian, thank you for the responses! 

I have two models which predict a value based on an input, one model takes into account around 2000 datapoints while the other takes into account the 14 in the table above, both models have an r^2 value of around .85.

I want to caution, that just because the model using only 14 datapoints has a high r^2 value, the low number of observations invalidates it.

Doing some reading on this, Cochran’s Formula seems relevant but it only provides a minimum amount of observations required for significance rather than a % value like a p value?

Comment: What would you think about a [confidence interval for $R^2?$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/175029/247274) What about adjusted $R^2?$

Comment: Hi Dave,

Thank you for this, I think bootstrapping is the way to go, it makes sense to me to get a CI, very interesting stuff!

Thanks again, appreciate the quick response!

Comment: @JonathanDevereux What do you mean by "invalidate"? A model can be invalid in the sense of not properly representing the true relationship with $R^2=.85$ and any arbitrarily large number of data points. $R^2$ isn't a comprehensive measure of validity, although neither is validity a term that is unambiguously defined. (I also believe but am not sure that when you write $r^2$ you mean the same thing as I mean with $R^2$.)

Comment: You can address the question whether $R^2$ is significantly different from zero using confidence intervals, however even if it is significant in that sense, this only means that the model explains *something* - it doesn't mean that it explains anything in a good way.